# why use str() is better than __str__()

Tags: python

Some time ago I asked one question, and a lot of people suggested me to change `__str__()` to `str(some object)`.

for example:

```
e_address   = f_name+l_name+year.__str__()+day.__str__()
```

Change to :

```
e_address   = f_name+l_name+str(year)+str(day)
```

So my question is why it is better? Are there any performance difference, or it is more pythonic way of programming?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__str__()` is the hook method that `str()` calls if it is present. The `str()` function will fall back to a sensible default if no such method is defined. Hooks are there to override the default behaviour, and you should not assume they are always implemented.

Moreover, it's more readable to just use the `str()` callable.

Answer (score 4):

It's less typing and the code is easier to read.